# Достижение максимальной глубины рекурсии при сериализации объектов SQLAlchemy в проекте на Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, memcached

Имеется подобие блога на Flask. Захотелось добавить кэширование при помощи Memcached.
Шел по рекомендациям данной статьи: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/flask-memcache#add-caching-to-flask
На главной странице блога имеются посты, и именно их я пытаюсь сериализовать при помощи sqlalchemy_serializer, используя метод to_dict():

```
@base.route('/')
def home():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    posts = cache.get(f'posts_{page}')
    if posts is None:
        posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.date.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=5)
        for post in posts.items:
            post.to_dict()
        # cache.set(f'posts_{page}', posts)
    return render_template('home.html', title='Home', posts=posts)
```

Модель поста соответственно:

```
import uuid
from datetime import datetime

from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
from sqlalchemy_serializer import SerializerMixin

from services import db


class Post(db.Model, SerializerMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'

    uuid = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_uuid = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), db.ForeignKey('users.uuid'), nullable=False)
    image = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, default='default.png')
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
```

Запустив приложение, отладчик выдал ошибку: sqlalchemy_serializer.serializer.IsNotSerializable: Unserializable type:<class 'web.users.models.User'> value:<User 95e9fb21-747d-4f0a-8783-4dbfb3ec5805>
Посчитав из сообщения об ошибке, что все понятно, дописал SerializerMixin к модели пользователя:

```
import uuid

from itsdangerous import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer as Serializer
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
from sqlalchemy_serializer import SerializerMixin

from services import db, login_manager
from config import Config


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_uuid):
    return User.query.get(user_uuid)


class User(db.Model, UserMixin, SerializerMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    uuid = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, default='default.png')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)

    def __init__(self, username, email, password):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password = password

    def get_id(self):
        return self.uuid

    def get_reset_token(self, expires_sec=30*60):
        s = Serializer(Config.SECRET_KEY, expires_sec)
        return s.dumps({'user_uuid': self.uuid}).decode('utf-8')

    @staticmethod
    def verify_reset_token(token):
        s = Serializer(Config.SECRET_KEY)
        try:
            user_uuid = s.loads(token)['user_uuid']
        except:
            return None
        return User.query.get(user_uuid)
```

Однако, данная правка привела к новой ошибке все в той же строке post.to_dict(): RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison.
Вопрос в следующем: связана ли это ошибка с тем, что таблицы взаимосвязаны (у поста есть автор, и у автора есть множество постов) и как эту проблему можно решить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема именно в том, что у вас двунаправленная ассоциация. Сериализатор просто не знает на каком уровне остановиться.

Нужно или в модели указать, что не нужно сериализировать (это будет использоваться при каждой операции):

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin, SerializerMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    # это для постов включит автора, но уже его посты не будет добавлять
    serialize_rules = ('-posts.author.posts',)
```

Или при самой операции задать до какого уровня сериализировать:

```
for post in posts.items:
    post.to_dict('-author.posts') # это исключит посты автора
```

Больше информации в документации https://pypi.org/project/SQLAlchemy-serializer/#Max-recursion